# What is the correct syntax for import images

Tags: react-native

I recently started using React Native and have problem with displaying local and external Images on Android emulator ([Pepperoni starter kit](https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit)). In example I have Simple component:

```js
class SomeView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const a = require("image!somepic")
        console.log(a)
        return (
            <View>
                <Image source={require("image!somepic")} style={styles.img}>
                    <Text>?</Text>
                </Image>

                <Image source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} style={[styles.img, { width: 50, height: 50 }]}>
                    <Text>?</Text>
                </Image>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is what I got:

[image]

Though, in real device, external image was loaded, but local also was not loaded.

What I got in console (is object for local image):

```
{
    "__packager_asset":true,
    "path":"D:\\Dev\\pepperoni-app-kit\\images\\somepic@3x.png",
    "uri":"somepic",
    "width":15.333333333333334,
    "height":45.333333333333336,
    "deprecated":true
}
```

I’m using React Native on Windows 10, ReactNative version 0.28.0. Local images located at folder `./images/`. (I include several sizes: `somepic.png`, `somepic@2x.png`, `somepic@3.png`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax that you are using to import images is the old syntax.  The new syntax is

```
<Image source={require("./images/somepic.png")}/>
```

See [Image guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) for more details.